# How to secure Python Flask APIs

Tags: python, flask

I created a bunch of RESTful API using Python, Flask and mongodb, mostly GET and POST.

I am planning to use this API in my mobile app, also to one of two trusted developers in the android applications they make.

I would like to know what's the possible & easiest way to secure the API to only the applications I authorize.

I don't want to use login or password. Is there any way i can authenticate using headers securely? or is there any alternative ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think especially for a scalable use I would use Flask-Restless together with Flask-JWT token authentication with token.

Here is a pretty nice example > https://github.com/graup/flask-restless-security

I am not sure I understand how you planning to authenticate without any user, or you just trying to lock app to use specific domain only?